# xdoclet vs xdoclet2?

Tags: java, hibernate, ant, xdoclet

I'm updating an old project & my version of xdoclet complains about my Java 1.5 annontations (ArrayList data = ....) when parsing for Hibernate (hibernate3) tags.

So my question is this...

Is there a fix for Xdoclet 1.2.3, or should I look to move to Xdoclet2?

I've already started moving some of the code over, but xdoclet2 doesn't seem to offer the same level of configuration for hibenate, such as excludedtags. I could be wrong on this though.

What do you lot think?

Jeff Porter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would definitively lose xdoclet in favor of JPA annotations. You can get about the same functionality from Hibernate using JPA annotations.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the original question: I had a similar (the same?) problem, which was caused by the version of xjavadoc distributed with xdoclet 1.2.3.

XJavadoc provided a snapshot release that fixes the compatibility. Replace the jar from the xdoclet-release with the one you can find as an attachment to [this JIRA issue](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MAVENUPLOAD-1399) (couldn't find a direct URL), and things should be better...